# Icon on Splash screen

Tags: boot

When I boot up or when the splash screen comes up asking for me to login I now get a small logo that looks like a briefcase half white and half blue with the word software next to it. I have tried to search for the meaning but I feel I'm not asking the right question. I'm new to Ubuntu so not much experience yet with the OD.

Any thoughts on the issue

Thanks

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.4 LTS